# Code performance, event listeners, multiple rotating boxes

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I've created a grid of 3D cubes using modulus, and the 3d cubes are were created from the Math and [Flash tutorial](http://www.flashandmath.com/advanced/menu3d/)

I have set up listeners so when the mouse hovers over a cube it starts to rotate:

```
private function setUpListeners():void {

      spBoard.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT,boardOut);

}
```

That works fine.

To begin the rotation of the cube when the mouse passes over it I have used:

```
     private function boardOut(e:MouseEvent):void {

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,rotateSquare);

        var i:int = 1;

        function rotateSquare(e:Event) {
            renderView(curTheta+i,curPhi+i); 
            i++;
         }
}
```

I can see why this would be inefficient, as it is running the loop every every frame, and for so many multiple cubes it just lags (very badly).

Does anybody have a better method of doing this? I'd be happy to post more code if people need/require it.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I should clarify, i'm hoping for the rotation to continue indefinitely  once the mouse moves off the cube.

2nd EDIT:

Here is how I am creating the cubes onto the "grid":

```
public function FlowerMenu(){

                var rowY:Number = 0;                    
                for (var i:int = 0; i < 190; i++) {
                    var myCube = new CubeMenu(["anemon.jpg","parodia.jpg","anagallis.jpg","lila.jpg","cosmos.jpg","adonis.jpg"],100);
                    myCube.x = 0 + ((i % 10) * 200);
                    if (i % 10 == 0) {
                        rowY += 200;
                    }
                    myCube.y = rowY;
                    addChild(myCube);


                }
```

Comment: Take a look at my (edited) answer.

Comment: Example added! =D - Ask for help if it doesn't match your setup... ;D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### New Answer:

In this case you can put every cube that you want to rotate in a Array and call ENTER_FRAME on the a container clip (not for every cube).

Looping through your Array (in the container) will be faster than dispatching tons of ENTER_FRAME events (I think).

(ask for examples if you need ;D)

---

### Example

Assuming `renderView` is a method of MenuCube, I suggest that you put all code needed for rotation inside `renderView` (information like `i++`, `curTheta` and `curPhi`).

```
// The container where every cube will reside
public var CubeContainer:Sprite;

// Creating Cubes, setting a listener to rotate them on MOUSE_OVER
// and adding them to the container.
public function CreateCubes()
{
    CubeContainer = new Sprite();

    for (var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var NewCube = new CubeMenu(/*...*/);

        NewCube.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, RotateMe);

        CubeContainer.addChild(NewCube);
    }

    CubeContainer.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, RotateCubes);
}

// When MOUSE_OVER fires, start rotating (by pushing it into an Array)
// and remove MOUSE_OVER listener
public function RotateMe(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var TargetCube:CubeMenu = e.currentTarget;

    CubesToRotate.push(TargetCube);
    TargetCube.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, RotateMe);
}

// ENTER_FRAME of the container...
// This will check every container that need to be rotated
// and call renderView for it.
public function RotateCubes(e:Event):void
{
    for(var i:int = 0; i <= CubesToRotate.length; i++)
    {
        var CurrentCube:CubeMenu = CubesToRotate[i];

        CurrentCube.renderView();
    }
}
```

---

### Old answer:

If I got it right, you can use MOUSE_OVER and MOUSE_OUT events:

```
private var i:int = 0;

private function setUpListeners():void
{
    spBoard.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, boardOver);
    spBoard.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, boardOut);
}

private function boardOver(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, rotateSquare);
}

private function boardOut(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, rotateSquare);
}

private function rotateSquare(e:Event)
{
    renderView(curTheta+i, curPhi+i); 
    i++;
}
```

This way your Mouse Events will be dispatched *only* when you move your mouse over and out the `spBoard`.

ps: As you see, the `i` variable must be defined outside the functions for this to work.

Comment: Thanks for this, at the moment I am using both MOUSE_OVER & MOUSE_OUT (didn't include MOUSE_OVER for sake of clarity). MOUSE_OVER controls the rotation of each cube, when the mouse hovers over the cube this works fine, as it's only one cube at a time it's dealing with. It's getting them rotating after a cursor has passed over them thats proving to be the problem.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll give it a shot. I'm relatively new to flash and AS3 so if you have an example that would be great.

Comment: Excellent, I'll give this a go on Monday!!

Answer (score 1):

Use a tweening library to do the animation (it replaces the enter frame event handler). Most of those libraries are much more efficient than doing it “by hand” with an enter frame handler, and for example will do multiple animation steps within a single handler. So instead of calling `n` functions (for `n` squares that needs to be rotated), it just calls a single function that does the animation at once.